Project migration from one Google Cloud account and organization to another account with possibly no organization
We're using 2 Google Cloud accounts. I sucessfully managed to transfer project ownership from one account to another and I managed to change the billing of the project from the billing in the old account to the billing in the new account. The end goal is for the old account to have nothing to do with the project any more. So, I don't have the access to the project in the old account anymore, beacuse the old owner was removed (but it could be added back if necessary).
The project was previously, in the old account, put into an organization (the project wasn't a part of 'No organization'). From what I can see if I now use
gcloud projects describe PROJECT_ID

in the new Google Cloud account shell, it looks like the project still resides in the "old" organization in the old account (according to the description it still has a parent of the organization type with the same ID as before the ownership change).
My thoughts & questions about the migration necessity:

If I leave the things as they are, what will happen with the project if sometime in the future the "old" organization ceases to exist? Or we actually delete the old account? Will the project still work or will it be shut down/deleted?
I guess I should take care of migrating the project to the new account anyway (better safe than sorry)?


The migration itself
The issue about the migration: the project is still part of the organization in the old account but I want to migrate it to the new account, but not necessarily to an organization. The thing is that I can't even start the migration in the new account. According to the documentation the migration can be quite simple: you go to the IAM & Admin > Identity & Organization and there you have the Migrate projects section with buttons Request and Accept. But I don't get to see this page content at all. It looks like I need to have an organization set up (either via Google Workspace either Cloud identity) before I can do this.
Questions about the migration:

Do I understand correctly that I need the organization inside the account to be able to migrate the project to the new account? Is it possible to do it without the organization? If so, how?
If I need to set up the organization, is there any other way than using Cloud Identity or Google Workspace?
Is this migration something that the support would be able to solve in a way that there's no need to do anything from our side?

